# segmentation fault in unordered_map after ~ 10000 keys added

Tags: c++, unordered-map, segmentation-fault

Segmentation fault occurs when datact=10736 when trying to insert into an unordered_map (see commented line for which call throws the fault). See below for attempted fixes.

When SIGSEGV is thrown it points me to line 764 of `hashtable_policy.h`

INPUT: data file with column1=counts, column2=16-character strings

PURPOSE: cluster 16-character sequences by adding all the counts of 1-substitution different sequences together. First sequence seen is "origin" by which all its 1-substitution friends are identified.

PSEUDOCODE: for each line in file:

1. read count, read sequence.
2. if sequence key_value exists in hash 'location' (type
   unordered_map), add current count;
3. otherwise make a new key_value, have it point to the count here, and
   assign all 1-substitution sequences to also point to this count.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>

#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int nuc2num(char currchar)
{   // returns 0,1,2,3 for A,C,T,G respectively
    int outnum;

    if (currchar=='A')
    {
        outnum=0;
    }
    else if (currchar=='C')
    {
        outnum=1;
    }
    else if (currchar=='T')
    {
        outnum=2;
    }
    else
    {
        outnum=3;
    }
    return outnum;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //command line arguments
    //  arg1=filename, arg2=barcode sequence length, arg3=#mismatches permitted

    //input handling
    //  file format: column 1 | column 2
    //               counts   | sequence    [int | string]

    string filename;
    string funnelstring;

    // define lookup matrix; rows=ACTG, cols = ACTG without row element
    Matrix <char> sub_lookup(4,3);
    sub_lookup[0][0] = 'C';
    sub_lookup[0][1] = 'T';
    sub_lookup[0][2] = 'G';
    sub_lookup[1][0] = 'A';
    sub_lookup[1][1] = 'T';
    sub_lookup[1][2] = 'G';
    sub_lookup[2][0] = 'A';
    sub_lookup[2][1] = 'C';
    sub_lookup[2][2] = 'G';
    sub_lookup[3][0] = 'A';
    sub_lookup[3][1] = 'C';
    sub_lookup[3][2] = 'T';

    int L,k;

    int j=0;

    const int buffersize=10000;
    int currentsize=buffersize;

    int datact=0;
    int currchar;

    vector <unsigned int> ctarr(buffersize);
    vector <string> seqarr(buffersize);

    filename=argv[1];
    L=atoi(argv[2]);
    k=atoi(argv[3]);

    unsigned int sct;
    int substrlen;
    string sequence,textct;
    ifstream seqfile (filename.c_str());

    //map <string,unsigned int*> location;
    unordered_map <string,unsigned int*> location;

    if (seqfile.is_open())
    {
        getline(seqfile,textct,'\n');
        while (textct != "")
        {
            sct=atoi(textct.c_str());
            substrlen=textct.length();
            //cout << textct << endl;
            sequence=textct.substr(substrlen-L,L);
            //cout << sequence << endl;

            //is there an associated guy?
            if (location.find(sequence) != location.end()) //just asks whether this key has been assigned
            {   //there's a value in the region
                *location[sequence]+=sct;
            }
            else
            {   //no value in region, make a footprint
                ctarr[datact]=sct;
                seqarr[datact]=sequence;
                location[sequence]=&ctarr[datact]; //assign current key to point to data count


                //assign k substitution "funnel" region to point to this count as well
                for (j=0; j<L; j++)
                {
                    funnelstring=sequence;
                    currchar = nuc2num(sequence[j]);

                    if (datact==10736 && j==13)
                    {
                        cout << "here" << endl;
                        cout << sequence << endl;
                    }

                    for (k=0; k<3; k++)
                    {
                        funnelstring[j]=sub_lookup[currchar][k];

//                    if (datact==10736 && j==13)
//                    {
//                        cout << funnelstring << endl;
//                        cout << location.max_size() << " | " << location.size() << endl;
//                        string asdf;
//                        asdf="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
//                        location[asdf]=&ctarr[datact]; //still segfaults
//                    }

                        if (location.find(funnelstring) == location.end()) // asks whether this key has been assigned
                        {   //this region is not assigned to another funnel
                            location[funnelstring]=&ctarr[datact]; //LINE THAT CAUSES SIGSEGV
                        }
                    }
                }
                datact++;
                cout << datact << endl;
                if (datact>=currentsize)
                {
                    ctarr.resize(currentsize+buffersize);
                    seqarr.resize(currentsize+buffersize);
                    currentsize+=buffersize;
                }
            }

            getline(seqfile,textct,'\n');
         }
        seqfile.close();
    }
```

Explorations.

1. It doesn't matter what key is added, when `datact==10736` and `j=13`, any
   key added to (unordered_map) location results in a SIGSEGV.
2. The line of code in question (marked by a comment above) is called many times prior, and operates correctly.
3. Exchanging unordered_map for map results in the same event, but at a different (higher) count of datact. Still low (between `datact`==16-35
   thousand).
4. Rewriting this code almost exactly, but with randomly generated 16-character sequences works perfectly, as far as I can tell (no
   segfaults for datact up to 200,000, didnt test higher).
5. In the code in (4), it does appear that there is a rehash right around 10000, which could be related or coincidence.

If need be, I can post the datafile that is read.

**EDIT: Solved**
Instead of `unordered_map <string,unsigned int*> location`, replaced with `unordered_map <string,unsigned int> location` (value_type is int instead of int*). Now value_type holds the index in the ctarr[]. Runs fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pointers to `vector` elements can be invalidated when you call `vector::resize()`. This is because the entire data may have to be moved around in order to find a contiguous memory block that fits the new size. In other words: As soon as you call `resize`, all your `location` data suddenly becomes useless garbage.

Possible solutions:

- Let `location` store the index of the required element in `ctarr` as its value rather than a pointer. (This will certainly not change the semantics of your program.)
- Let `location` store the actual `unsigned int`  value instead of a pointer. Depending on your program logic and how you change and access this data, this may not be what you want.

Also note that although the segfault occurs in `hashtable_policy.h`, this bug has nothing to do with the implementation of `unordered_map` (or `vector`) - it is entirely your fault for not reading the reference for `vector::resize()` ;-) : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/ (section 'Iterator validity')

---

The other thing I noticed about your code is that you use `operator[]` for accessing your `vector` elements. This disables out-of-bounds checking. If I came across an error like yours in my code (hard to trace back because it occurs somewhere far from my erroneous code), my first course of action would be swapping `operator[]` for `vector::at()` (actually, I always start with `at()` and only switch if I can prove beyond reasonable doubt that bounds checking is a performance bottleneck for this particular purpose). This would not have helped with your problem, but is often an invaluable help in spotting mistakes.

Comment: It's funny, I came up with the pointer idea because I thought that would be more memory efficient, and it ended up causing headaches. One reason I didn't catch this is because it occurred at 10736. If it had occurred at 10001, I would have immediately looked at what's going on in the vector resize. Also, it shouldn't try to add to location unless that key_value is new. The error I'd expect is that the program would run fine until trying to iterate the target of the pointer, when the pointer no longer points to a real value (`*location[sequence]+=sct;`)

Comment: @vector07 In general, storing the pointer may easily be *less* memory efficient. On an x86_64 system with gcc, an `unsigned int` (for storing the value or the index) takes 4 bytes, whereas a pointer takes 8 bytes!